# How do I overwrite Facet API tokens for active items?

Tags: tokens, search

I'm using "Facet API" and "Search facets" modules on Drupal 7. I'm trying to change the values of the active items' tokens provided in the search blocks (especially the [facetapi_active:facet-label] token) , I tried to use the[image] "Facet API Bonus" module and the function hook_facet_items_alter with no success, could someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't need the "Facet API Bonus" module, I wrote a module to implement THEME_facetapi_link_active (included in facetapi.theme.inc)
then i simply replaced the label's text using the function `str_replace` like this:

```
$variables['text']=str_replace("Price » Amount (decimal)","Price",$variables['text']);
```